# Find the surface area of paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$, for $0\leq z\leq2$

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

> Find the surface area of paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$, for $0\leq z\leq2$.

I've done the majority of this problem and had my limits of integration to be $0$ to $\sqrt2$ and $0$ to $2\pi$, with my integrand being $\sqrt{1+4(x^2+y^2)}$. My answer ends up being $13\pi/3$. It seems a little small, are my limits of integration wrong?

Comment: Your integral is definitely wrong. You should use polar coordinate transformation in iterative integrations to calculate the area. So the integrand shouldn't be like that.

Comment: Would an integral from 1 to 9 and 0 to 2*pi be correct, after converting to polar?

Comment: In polar, radius goes from $0$ to $\sqrt 2$

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
$
One of the parametrizations of the surface is $r:S \to \R^3$

$$r(u,v) = (u, v, u^2+v^2)$$

where $S = \{(x,y) \in\R^2|\rho \le \sqrt{2}\}$ and $\rho(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.
The derivatives of the surface are

$$r_u = (1, 0, 2u)\\
r_v = (0, 1, 2v)$$
Hence, the cross product of them is $ r_u \times r_v = -(2u, 2v, 1) $ whose Euclidean norm is $ |r_u \times r_v| = \sqrt{4u^2 + 4v^2 + 1} $.

By definition of surface area on $S$, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_area)

\begin{aligned}
A
&= \int_{S} |r_u \times r_v| du dv\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}} \rho\sqrt{4\rho^2 + 1} d\rho d\theta\\
&=\dfrac{13}{3}\pi
\end{aligned}

Turned out your solution is correct?

Answer (score 0):

So, we want to find the surface area of the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ that lies between the planes $z=0$ and $z=2$.

Surface area is given by $S=\iint_D\sqrt{1+(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})^2}dA$.

We have: $(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^2=4x^2$
$\hspace{17mm}$$(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})^2=4y^2$

So, $S=\iint_D\sqrt{1+(4x^2+4y^2})dA$.

Now, converting to polar and finding our limits of integration, we know $x^2+y^2=r^2$, and since $x^2+y^2=z$ where $0\leq z \leq 2$,

$0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2}$

Furthermore, we want to integrate around the entire paraboloid, so $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Therefore, we have:
\begin{align}
S&=\iint_D\sqrt{1+(4x^2+4y^2})dA\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{1+4r^2}\hspace{1mm}rdrd\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\hspace{2mm}\cdot\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}r\sqrt{1+4r^2}dr\\
&=2\pi(\frac{13}{6})=\boxed{\frac{13\pi}{3}}
\end{align}

you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

How is the formula for calculating surface area is taken as?:

$S=\int\int_D \sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2} dA$